# How to design a iPhone like menu/button in android at the bottom?

Tags: android, menu, android-tabhost

I have googled this, most of the solutions are using:

1.TabHost with customized style which would cover the separate line between each tab to archive the requirement. 
2.On the android developers website, there is a article is using Merge layout to put 2 buttons on top of the background image kind of archive what I want.(http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)
3.What about using button but style the looking like the example below? I don't need the selection, cause each item in the menu will be a button, which takes the user to another page.

I am wondering is there any other solutions apart from these two?

This is something want:
[image]

I don't need the menu likes a tab which has selected and unselected, they are better like a button always displaying in certain screen(activity).

Thank you.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for but I would want to ask if it's really necessary to do this? It is usually much preferable to use the standard UI patterns for a platform since that's what the users will be familiar and comfortable with. You risk making your app confusing and hard to use if you try to "transplant" UI elements from one platform to another.

Comment: As you build your app for Android, don't carry over themed UI elements from other platforms and don't mimic their specific behaviors. Review the Building Blocks section in this styleguide to learn about Android's most important UI elementsand the way they look in the system default ts.  customize carefully according to your specific branding - and not according to the conventions of a different platform - source : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple buttons, and provide any custom background for it. For such simple form as on your screenshot look for [this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

But @Janne write right thing - you should be very careful with transplanting controls from another platforms.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because for certain action, you can't assume user will know if they press menu button they will find what they need to do, e.g. go to see the Menu in this screenshot. So I have to put something in the screen to let user know, what they can do in this screen.

Comment: In Android everyone knows that there is menu - if they need to do some action they will look at menu. Only most popular actions appears on the screen as buttons.

Comment: In this case, if I use button, I think I need to force my layout from top to buttom with a imageview, followed by a textview then a nested linear layout which has few buttons from left to right, I do not want to add these buttons on top of the textview, which could cover the bottom 1-2 lines of contents. how do I style the textview which just fit the space between the imageview and the bottom linearlayout with buttons?

Comment: Use this param of linear layout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight

Comment: I have to ask: if you use this instead of the menu, what are you going to put in the menu? I'd get _very_ frustrated as a user if I press the menu button and nothing happens, and I don't know that I'd be much happier if I just get a repeat of the (space-stealing) bottom bar either.